# Laravel 5.6 get id of request in middleware from resource

Tags: php, laravel

my resource route:

```
Route::resource('imagerequests', 'ImageRequestController');
```

It looks like this in the browser:

```
/imagerequests/19/edit
```

In my controllers contructor I do this because I need the middleware only when the user goes to the edit page:

```
$this->middleware('edit')->only('edit');
```

My editMiddleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    dd($request->id);
}
```

This returns `null`

I've tried this too and also returns `null`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    dd($request->imagerequests);
}
```

How can I access the id when I go to

### EDIT

result of `dd($request);`

```
Request {#42 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure {#295 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure {#302 ▶}
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#44 ▼
    #parameters: []
  }
  +request: ParameterBag {#50 ▼
    #parameters: []
  }
  +query: ParameterBag {#50 ▶}
  +server: ServerBag {#46 ▶}
  +files: FileBag {#47 ▶}
  +cookies: ParameterBag {#45 ▶}
  +headers: HeaderBag {#48 ▶}
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/imagerequests/19/edit"
  #requestUri: "/imagerequests/19/edit"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "GET"
  #format: null
  #session: Store {#356 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -isHostValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  basePath: ""
  format: "html"
}
```

### EDIT 2

result of `dd($next);`

```
Closure {#294 ▼
  class: "Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline"
  this: Pipeline {#310 …}
  parameters: {▶}
  use: {▶}
  file: "C:\Users\EXM235\Desktop\acl-poc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php"
  line: "28 to 36"
}
```

Comment: what does `dd($request);` returns ?

Comment: @dexter I edited OP with the results of ´dd($request)´

Comment: what does dd($next); returns ?

Comment: @dexter i updated OP with rhe results of dd($next);

Comment: Are you trying to determine whether or not the user can edit this resource?

Comment: @adam depending on the status (a field of the ImageRequest resource) I want to block the user from editing it, that's correct

Comment: You might be able to accomplish this via policies: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#writing-policies. If you scroll a bit further you'll notice an example using the `->middleware` syntax: `->middleware('can:update,post');`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this works for Middleware in the same way it does for Controllers, but in a Controller you'd typehint the model coming from the URL like so:

```
public function handle($request, Imagerequest $imagerequest, Closure $next)
{
    $imagerequest->id
}
```

Of course, you'd also need to add at the beginning:

```
use App\Imagerequest;
```